# data won't appear with getjson (undefined)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, getjson

The api data appears as undefined and I don't understand why.
Here is my HTML code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://data.iledefrance.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=repertoire-bibliotheques&q=&refine.typeinst=Mus%C3%A9e", function(json) {
    console.log(json.records.fields);
    console.log(json);

    var recordid = '';
    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
      recordid += '<tr>';
      recordid += '<td>' + value.nometablissement + '</td>';
      recordid += '<td>' + value.telephone + '</td>';
      recordid += '<td>' + value.codepostal + '</td>';
      recordid += '<td>' + value.commune + '</td>';
      recordid += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#recordid_table').append(recordid);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1>Musées Parisiens</h1>
    <br />
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="recordid_table">
      <tr>
        <th>Nom de l'établissemnt</th>
        <th>Numéro de Téléphone</th>
        <th>Code Postal</th>
        <th>Commune</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS code:

I don't understand why does the data appears as undefined in the table. Here is my dataset if it can help answer my question: https://data.iledefrance.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=repertoire-bibliotheques&q=&refine.typeinst=Mus%C3%A9e
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You've to read the datapaths more carefully. `$.each` reads only the topmost level of the object, hence `value` in the callback gets values like `nhits <Int>`, `parameters <Object>`, __`records <Array>`__ ... A `nometablissement ` can be found at `value.records[0].fields.nometablissement`, but it also occurs in the other indices of `records`.

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is deeper than the way you are treating it.

The array you need to loop over is `json.records` and each record has a `fields` object where the properties you are wanting are

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://data.iledefrance.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=repertoire-bibliotheques&q=&refine.typeinst=Mus%C3%A9e", function(json) {
    var recordid = '';
    $.each(json.records, function(key, value) {
      var fields = value.fields;
      recordid += '<tr>';
      recordid += '<td>' + fields.nometablissement + '</td>';
      recordid += '<td>' + fields.telephone + '</td>';
      recordid += '<td>' + fields.codepostal + '</td>';
      recordid += '<td>' + fields.commune + '</td>';
      recordid += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#recordid_table').append(recordid);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1>Musées Parisiens</h1>
    <br />
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="recordid_table">
      <tr>
        <th>Nom de l'établissemnt</th>
        <th>Numéro de Téléphone</th>
        <th>Code Postal</th>
        <th>Commune</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```